# Keeping history of splitted repository on renamed folder

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Let's assume repository of my project has a folder like:

```
test/EFG
```

which is renamed from:

```
test/ABC
```

Now I'm trying to split `EFG` folder into new repository. I'm using following command:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter test/EFG master
```

It works great, but there is a big downside. Using this command, It only transfer history **after** renaming to `EFG` folder. Is there anyway to keep history **before** renaming to `EFG` too (history of folder when it was named `ABC`)?

Answer (score -2):

```
git subtree split
```

.... this should be able to do, what you want. The git documentation says the following about it:

*Extract a new, synthetic project history from the history of the  subtree. The new history includes only the commits (including merges) that affected `prefix`, and each of those commits now has the contents of  at the root of the project instead of in a subdirectory. Thus, the newly created history is suitable for export as a separate git repository.*

Please refer to https://lostechies.com/johnteague/2014/04/04/using-git-subtrees-to-split-a-repository/ for a more detailed description of how to use it.

Comment: For `git subtree` in this case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304941/follow-renames-when-performing-git-subtree-split may be a better reference.